# php, compare arrays and append difference

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays:

1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Type 1
            [rate] => 100.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Type 2
            [rate] => 75.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Type 3
            [rate] => 50.00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Type 4
            [rate] => 50.00
        )
)
```

2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Type 1
            [rate] => 125
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Type 2
            [rate] => 85
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Type 3
            [rate] => 65
        )

)
```

What I need to do is compare the two arrays, and append missing items from 1st array to the 2nd one. This will always be the case first array will have more items than the second one.

I have tried using something like:

```
$result = array_udiff($array1,$array2,
 function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
    return $obj_a->name - $obj_b->name;
  }
);
```

but it just returns an empty array

Comment: Is the minus in `return $obj_a->name - $obj_b->name;` a typo just present here? There should be a `==`.

Comment: It's unclear what constitutes a _missing item_. You only care about the objects `name` member being different?

Comment: Your question requires clarification because your example is unclear.  Your first array has a name = 'Type 1' with a rate of 100.00 whereas the 2nd array has a 'Type 1' with a rate of 125.  What constitutes a "new" element that should be appended to array2?

Comment: @gview values in this case dont matter. Maybe I should use the array keys to compare the difference

Comment: If the array of objects where the same, you could use array_merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
<?php

    $arr1 = array(
        (object)array("id"=>1,"name"=>"type 1","rate"=>100.00),
        (object)array("id"=>2,"name"=>"type 2","rate"=>75.00),
        (object)array("id"=>3,"name"=>"type 3","rate"=>50.00),
        (object)array("id"=>4,"name"=>"type 4","rate"=>50.00)
        );

    $arr2 = array(
        (object)array("name"=>"type 1","rate"=>125),
        (object)array("name"=>"type 2","rate"=>85),
        (object)array("name"=>"type 3","rate"=>65)
        );


    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr1);$i++){

        $count=0;
        for($j=0;$j<sizeof($arr2);$j++){

            if($arr1[$i]->name == $arr2[$j]->name){

                $count++;
            }
        }

        if($count==0){

            array_push($arr2,(object)array("name"=>$arr1[$i]->name,"rate"=>$arr1[$i]->rate));
        }
    }

    print_r($arr2);
?>
```

Comment: I hope I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be complicated, assuming that you allow the arrays to contain objects of the same type and structure.  We don't have enough context given the question to understand whether there is a good reason you can't.

```
//$array1 original array
//$array2 target array

$array2 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```